# Remove element between two different matching pattern in r

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Hello I have a string such as

```
string="some containt[OKUUUDN?DD];some other contaian[HDJD.HHD]"
```

how can I remove part between `[` and `]`?

I tried :

```
gsub("[&]", "", string)
```

I should get :

```
"some containt;some other contaian"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\\[.*?]` to remove everything between `[` and `]`. `[` needs to be escaped `\\[`, `.` means everything, `*` means repeated 0 to n, `?` means non greedy to remove not everything from the first to the last match.

```
gsub("\\[.*?]", "", string)
#[1] "some containt;some other contaian"
```